# GDK Android Emulator

Tags: google-gdk

I have a sample program with static card for google glass using GDK.  How can i run it?
I have created an emulator from this following link, http://mobilevangelist.com/2014/01/02/gdk-and-the-android-emulator/
but once i run my application it show Card class not found.
similarly i tried with http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html
i cant able to run my sample program.

Kindly give some ideas to run GDK app without Google Glass.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

Note that the post you reference says the following:

> It turns out you can do some things in an Android emulator when
>   developing for Glass. **Most of the functionality specific to Glass
>   won’t work**, but those Android paradigms that can run on Glass do work.
>   These are limited to Activity layouts and some interactions.

You can't run any of the Glass specific classes, like Cards, on the emulator.  You can only preview your layouts if they are done with Android layout resources.